# How to get Auto-completion in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

In ASP.NET MVC, we don't have controls which can do stuffs such as autocompletion (we don't have controls at all from Visual Studio like in web forms).

**But, Is it possible to still get 'Auto-completion' with a text box in ASP.NET MVC** (like with the textbox found on the Google's Home page)?

**If this is the case, what's the best way to do so?** JQueryUI? or there's someother way of getting that functionality?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like the one in the jquery ui?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: @Chobo2 -- I've just check the link and that's what I want. Still, I'd like to know if that's the only way to obtain that functionality (i.e. using JQueryUI). If it's the only way, I'm fine with that.

Comment: Well before JqueryUI. There where other other auto complete plugins. But as far as other ways go. I don't think so. You can roll out your own but that still would be javascript/jquery. I don't think it is possible to make an auto complete just using asp.net MVC(nor even with webforms) as you would have to do a post back every single time to send the letters they are typing in. You need some sort of ajax to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

To use [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) with ASP.NET MVC you can do the following:

Step 1 : Create the textbox

```
<%= Html.TextBox("searchBox",null,new { @class="large", autocomplete="on"}) %>
```

Step 2 : Create action to do search function (I am using NHibernate to query DB, but the key is to return an string with each result delimited by a newline)

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string q) {

  var programs = programRepository
                   .Search(q)
                   .ToList()
                   .ConvertAll(x => x.ProgramName)
                   .ToArray();

  return new ContentResult {Content = string.Join("\n", programs) };
}
```

Step 3: turn on autocomplete functionality in your HTML (place inside a script block)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#searchBox').autocomplete("/Controller/Autocomplete", { autoFill: true, minChars: 2 });

});
```